# Page rotator for webview C# - Windows IOT app

Tags: c#, windowsiot

I am trying to create a C# Windows Blank App that has a simple webview that cycles through multiple URLs obtained from an XML file.

This is what I have so far:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;

        //creates url array

        List<Uri> listUri = new List<Uri>();

        listUri.Add(new Uri("http://www.bing.com/"));
        listUri.Add(new Uri("https://www.youtube.com/"));
        listUri.Add(new Uri("http://hsrg.lsu.edu/"));

        foreach (Uri value in listUri)
        {
            webView.Navigate(value);
        }

    }
```

I don't know how to browse and use an XML file so I have an list setup right now. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml) to parse the URLs in XML file like this:

```
        XElement xelement = XElement.Load("URLs.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> urls = xelement.Elements();
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            var value = url.Element("Address").Value;
            webView.Navigate(new Uri(value));
        }
```

And the URLs.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Urls>
  <Url>
    <Address>http://www.bing.com/</Address>
  </Url>
  <Url>
    <Address>https://www.youtube.com/</Address>
  </Url>
  <Url>
    <Address>http://hsrg.lsu.edu/</Address>
  </Url>
</Urls>
```